# How to trim offset of a folded cascode op-amp when different voltage in applied to the input portion?

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc-offset, offset

[image: Circuit]When the common mode input voltage is varied, offset is also varied. How can I trim them without using any pot?

Comment: Can you edit your question and draw a schematic with the tool?

Comment: @VoltageSpike Here it is

Answer (score 0):

To trim the offset of a folded cascode op amp, you would typically:

Adjust the bias currents of the input differential pair transistors (Q1/Q2 in a typical schematic) to get the DC balance/offset close
Adjust the "tail" current source (for the common emitter node of the diff pair) to fine tune the offset
Optionally adjust the bias of the common-gate stage (Q5/Q6) to further tweak offset, if it's significant

The key thing is you want to adjust currents, not voltages, as that will keep the op amp operating properly under different input voltage ranges.
So in short: use current trims/adjustments, not voltage adjustments, to null the offset, and that approach will be robust to varying input voltage ranges.

Comment: **Warning:** Systems have detected this answer may be AI-generated (e.g. ChatGPT) and therefore may be untrustworthy. Exercise additional caution when relying on its contents. It may be deleted in future.

Comment: Your answer is generically vagiely correct but gives no clue at all as to how anything can be done "without a pot".  || The reference to "the common gate stage" is extremely generic and seems to assume a very standardised circuit. Can you explain how it applies to the diagram ? (posted by the Op after you posted you answer).